# ВодИЧка но водОЧка

Tags: словообразование

Почему уменьшительно-ласкательное к слову вода - водичка, а не водочка, как например, булка - булочка?

Answer (score 2):

"Водичка" - уменьшительно-ласкательное не к "вода", а к "водица".

- Вода -> водица -> водичка
- Пта[ха] -> птица -> птичка

Но

- Лодка -> Лодочка
- Кадка -> Кадочка

Comment: Мне тоже так показалось. Вот нашел на [Gramma.Ru](http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.19): "Суффикс **-ичк-** пишется у существительных женского рода, образованных от основ на **иц**: лестничка (лестниц-а), луковичка (луковиц-а), пуговичка (пуговиц-а), умничка (умниц-а)." Интересно. (0:

Comment: Всё так. Только у _водички_ суффикс не **-ичк**. См.: **вод**-а -> вод-**иц**-а -> вод _ич_-**к**-а (вод+**ич**+**к**+а).

Comment: Слава, а чем в данном случае является ***ич***?

Comment: ======= Суффиксом.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, что здесь  два суффикса - ***ич*** и ***к*** ?

Comment: Да. И Тихонов так считает ("Словообразовательный словарь русского языка"). И Ефремова с Кузнецовой ("Словарь морфем русского языка").

Answer (score 2):

1) В русском языке суффикс нет суффикса ИЧК с уменьшительно-ласкательным значением, поэтому:

вод/а - вод/иц/а - вод/ич/к/а, чередование Ц/Ч в мотивирующей основе (в первом суффиксе).

2) Водк/а - водоч/к/а, суффикс К, О - беглая гласная в основе, 
также лодк/а - лодоч/к/а.

3) Интересно: улица - ул/очк/а, суффикс ОЧК, усечение основы на ИЦ.

Comment: _Vera: "В русском языке суффикс нет суффикса ИЧК с уменьшительно-ласкательным значением"._ === Есть. К примеру, здесь: http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/145388

Comment: В словаре Ефремовой дается только суффикс ИЧК со значением лица ж. пола: математика - математичка (разг.) А кроме "ведомостички" ничего нет, а то это слово, скорее, на  окказионали́зм похоже?

Comment: _Vera: "...это слово, скорее, на окказионали́зм похоже"_ === Ну что я могу поделать? Похоже. Тем не менее, Ефремова его в своих словарях отмечает, и суффикс-то в нём ИЧК.

Comment: Вряд ли разумно менять что-либо в словарях из-за одного придуманного слова, это была бы такая маленькая "глупостичка".

Comment: Чума - чумичка.

Comment: Итак,  хвала тебе, Чума, чумичка ты, а не чума!   (А.С. Пушкин). А как насчет настоящей чумички, откуда она взялась?  ЧУМИЧКА, 1. Устар. Поварёшка, разливательная ложка. 2. Разг.-сниж. Грязнуля, замарашка (первоначально - женщина из низших сословий; служанка, выполняющая грязную работу). Ходить чумичкой. Умойся, ч.!

Comment: Вера, а чем тогда являются, такие слова, как лестничка, пуговица — пуговичка, ножницы — ножнички? Здесь суффикс ***ичк*** разве не с с уменьшительно-ласкательным значением?

Comment: Лестнич/к/а, пугович/к/а, ножнич/к/и, здесь чередование Ц/Ч в основе и суффикс К. Проверено по словарю Тихонова.

Comment: В пособиях  ***Домашний репетитор, Русский язык, Русский язык, Весь курс, И.Б. Голуб, Д.Э. Розенталь"***   ***Ичк*** - суффикс.

Comment: Наверное, опечатка. ИЧ+К выделяется во всех словообразовательных словарях и у Ефремовой в "Толковом словаре словообразовательных частиц". Да и логика понятна, допустим: пуговиц/а - пугов/ичк/а. Получается, что надо усекать основу на ИЦ, а потом добавлять этот же элемент в составе суффикса.